# If statement not properly working

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm new to java and having an issue with my code, the program compliles just fine, but I'm having a problem with the if statement in TreatHouse.java, `if ((totalCandy > 0) && (treatsPerTreater < totalCandy)) {`
is not giving me the right output. I'm trying to figure out how to fix that as well as improve my current code so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Halloween {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Which candy should we give out first? Candy in pot 1 or candy in pot 2?");
        int candyPot = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How much candy did we buy?");
        int totalCandy = scan.nextInt();

        TreatHouse ourHouse = new TreatHouse(candyPot, totalCandy);

        while (ourHouse.getCandyCount() > 0) {
            ourHouse.getCandyStatus(); //tells how much candy is left & other stuff

            System.out.println("How much candy per treater should we give out?");
            int treatsPerTreater = scan.nextInt();
            ourHouse.setTreatsPerTreater(treatsPerTreater);

            System.out.println("Knock, knock...." + "Trick or treat!");
            ourHouse.knockKnock();
            ourHouse.passOutCandy();
        }

        System.out.println("Time to turn off the lights and go to bed!");
        System.out.println("The last candy came from pot number"+ ourHouse.getLastPot());
        System.out.println("Happy Halloween!");
        scan.close();
    }
}












import java.util.Random;

public class TreatHouse {
    int candyPot1; //amount of candy in pot 1
    int candyPot2; //amount of candy in pot 2
    int currentPot; //1 or 2
    int totalCandy;
    int currentTreaters; 
    int treatsPerTreater;

    public TreatHouse(int candyPot, int totalCandy) {
        //Add code here, be sure to split the candy between the pots.
      currentPot = candyPot;
      if (totalCandy <=0) {
          System.out.println("We can't give out candy if we don't have amy. I think we have some from last year. " +
                             "Yep, we have 100 pieces of candy to give out.");
          totalCandy = 100;
          candyPot1 = totalCandy/2;
          candyPot2 = totalCandy/2;
      }

      if (totalCandy > 0) {
          totalCandy = totalCandy;
          candyPot1 = totalCandy/2;
          candyPot2 = totalCandy/2;
      }                            
    }

    public int getCandyCount() {
        return candyPot1 + candyPot2;
    }

    public void passOutCandy() {
        //If there are enough treats per treater for the given amount per treater, pass out candy
        //from the current pot and switch to the other one.
        //Else display a message that the treaters have been tricked... (no candy for them.)
        // but do not change the current pot
        if ((totalCandy > 0) && (treatsPerTreater < totalCandy)) {
          if (true) {
             if (currentPot == 1) {
                 candyPot1 = candyPot1 - (this.currentTreaters*treatsPerTreater);
                 currentPot = 2;
             }

             if (currentPot == 2) {
                 candyPot2 = candyPot2 - (this.currentTreaters*treatsPerTreater);
                 currentPot = 1;
             }

             // System.out.println("Pot " + currentPot + " doesn't exist. Try again next time");
          }
      }
      else
          System.out.println("You have been tricked! No candy for you >:D!!!!");             
    }


    //Sets the number of trick or treaters.
    public void knockKnock() {
        Random gen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        this.currentTreaters = gen.nextInt(13) + 1; //1 to 13 treaters.
    }

    //Displays how much candy in each pot, total candy left

    public void getCandyStatus() {
        //add in code here
      System.out.println("Candy in Pot1: " + candyPot1 + "  Candy in Pot2: " + candyPot2);
      System.out.println("Total candy left: " + (candyPot1 + candyPot2));

    }

    //returns the pot number for which candy was last given.
    public int getLastPot() {
        //add code here
      if (currentPot == 1 || currentPot == 2) {
          if (currentPot == 2) {
              currentPot = 1;
              return currentPot;
          }
          if (currentPot == 1) {
              currentPot = 2;
              return currentPot;
          }
      }
      else 
          return currentPot;

      return 1;
    }

    public void setTreatsPerTreater(int treatsPerTreater) {
        //add code here
      treatsPerTreater = treatsPerTreater;
    }
}
```

Comment: “Questions seeking debugging help must include the ***desired behavior***, a ***specific problem*** or error and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without ***a clear problem statement*** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).” — Ideally your question should contain the _expected_ behavior and the _current_ behavior. “Not giving me the right output” is useless as a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable name `totalCandy` for both a local method parameter name as well as a field name.

change this line

```
totalCandy = totalCandy;
```

to

```
this.totalCandy = totalCandy;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to follow your logic completely, but here's what I got:
You have totalCandy as a Field and a parameter. If you call the constructor with with (1, -3), then the field (class variable) is assigned 100. At the next if statement, which of the totalCandy is used? I don't remember how java handles that, but you might want to use this.totalCandy to refer to the class variable and the parameter without this to avoid confusion. 
In getCandyCount() you have candyPot1 + candyPot2, but those values were set in the if statement as totalCandy / 2. If totalCandy is odd, you will count will be off by one as integer division truncates the remainder. 
Finally, your if (true) is totally unnecessary. As for the if statement where you are having issue, I would make sure that the other stuff are handled first then check if it still occurs.

Comment: The `if(true)` is most likely temporarily there for testing the previous `if` statement.

Comment: no, the field totalCandy is never assigned, he reassigns the local parameter in both cases.

Comment: @Avezou How would I fix the integer truncation? The logic behind it is if I input for 41(any odd number) candies and that needs to be split correctly, I'm going to get 20 for both pots, how would I code that to get 20 and 21 in the proper pots?

Comment: @YellowBird, how about something like `pot1 = totalCandy / 2;  pot2 = totalCandy - pot1`. in other words.  first pot is 41 / 2 = 20 (integer division). second pot is 41 - 20 = 21

Comment: I'm now having a problem with the program says I need a return in this statement,  if (currentPot == 1 || currentPot == 2) { 
          if (currentPot == 2) { // returns the last pot that candy was taken from
              currentPot = 1;
              return currentPot;
          }
          if (currentPot == 1) {
              currentPot = 2;
              return currentPot;
          }
      }
      else 
          return currentPot;
 }
I don't understand why it needs a return when It has one in the else statement so it should return something no matter what? How do i fix that

Comment: The function needs to return a value. If you have a return in the else block, it will only return if the condition is false. You need to return a value with the condition is true.